# Updating data fields using PHP

Tags: php, html

I am a complete beginner when it comes to PHP. I have successfully created a login form/page that requires a user to enter his/her username and password which is then added to a database. I have also managed to create a page (using php) to display the data contained in all the data fields. I have the db connection file separately which works well. I have a functions.php file which contains the functions.

Now, I have created a php file in which I should be able to update the data in the various fields in the database. Instead of updating/replacing the existing data (username & password) in the selected row (targeting the id) it creates a new row in the db with the new username & password. Herewith my code to update existing data fields.

```
<?php include "db.php";?>
<?php include "functions.php";?>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];    
    $id = $_POST['id'];    

    $query = "UPDATE users SET ";
    $query .= "username = '$username', ";
    $query .= "password = '$password', ";
    $query .= "WHERE id = $id ";  

        $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
        if(!$result) {

            die("QUERY FAILED" . mysqli_error($connection));
        }


}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>

 <div class="container">

     <div class="col-sm-6">

      <form action="login_create.php" method="post">

            <div class="form-group">
            <label for="username">Username</label>
            <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control">
             </div>

            <div class="form-group">
             <label for="password">Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control">
            </div> 

            <div class="form-group">
            <select name="id" id="">

    <?php
    showAllData();  

    ?>

            </select>
            </div>

            <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="submit" value="UPDATE">

         </form>          

     </div>

 </div>     

</body>
</html>
```

I can simply not find the problem. Since people use PHP differently I am unable to find a solution based on the specific coding I have tried.

### Update

Kindly note that I am working on a localhost as part of learning php and have not yet started looking at security. I am initialising the $connection via a different file (db.php) which I am calling in the first line of my previous code.

```
    <?php
$connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'loginapp'); 
    if(!$connection) {            
    die("Database connection failed");        
    }
?>
```

Comment: `UPDATE` query __cannot__ create a new row. Also you have a syntax error in query text. I suppose your form is submitted to incorrect url provided in `action` attribute.

Comment: use `INSERT` statement to create a new row, but keep in mind if you've declared a `primary key` in the 'users' table(in fact and logically, the `id` column should be declared as  `primary key` and the `username` should be declared as `unique`) the `INSERT` won't work and it will give you an error as there's data duplication in the table.

Comment: Your form is posting to `action="login_create.php"` if the filenaming is correct, it's doing what it should. Creating a new login.

Comment: **Warning:** _Never store passwords in clear text!_ Only store password hashes Use PHP's [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) .

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use parameterized [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of manually building your queries like that. Specially since you're not escaping the user inputs at all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you didn't say what does the login_create.php do and what is the filename of that php code in your post. I can only guess that your `login_create.php` file is to create a new account not update it. Perhaps your file with that `UPDATE` query is not named `login_create.php`. Hence, my guess is that you put a wrong filename in your `<form action="login_create.php" method="post">`

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted solution on behalf of the question author)*.

The problem was with the incorrect naming of the form action. I used

```
<form action="login_create.php" method="post">
```

instead of

```
<form action="login_update.php" method="post">
```